# Azure - Cannot change NIC security group using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-2.x

Why doesn't Azure doesn't let me update Network security group of existing NIC?

I get the error `The resource 'Ubuntu915' already exists`.

[azure_rm_networkinterface](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_networkinterface_module.html) module documentation says it can be used to modify NIC configurations.

```
  - name: Get facts for one network interface
    azure_rm_networkinterface_info:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      name: "{{ azure_vm_network_interface }}"
    register: azure_network_interface_info


  - name: Applying NSG to target NIC
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      name: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      subnet_name: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].subnet }}"
      virtual_network: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].virtual_network.name }}"
      ip_configurations:
        - name: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].name }}"      
          primary: "{{ test1 }}"
          private_ip_address: "{{ test2  }}"
          private_ip_allocation_method: "{{ test3 }}"
          public_ip_address_name: "Ubuntu-915-test"
          public_ip_allocation_method: "Dynamic"     
      security_group: "testing_temp_8"
```

`Error:`

```
 "msg": "Error creating or updating network interface Ubuntu915 - 
(InvalidResourceLocation) The resource 'Ubuntu915' already exists in location 'eastus' in resource
 group 'cloud-shell-storage-centralindia'. A resource with the same name cannot be created in 
location 'centralindia'. Please select a new resource name.\nCode: 
InvalidResourceLocation\nMessage: The resource 'Ubuntu915' already exists in location 'eastus' in 
resource group 'cloud-shell-storage-centralindia'. A resource with the same name cannot be created 
in location 'centralindia'. Please select a new resource name."
     }
```

Comment: The name must be globally unique , Could you please try with some unique name .!?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29607#issuecomment-376493384

Comment: Name of the interface or the public IP? Either way I don't want to create a new IP or Interface. I want to update the the existing resource.

Comment: The name which you want to provide make sure that ,There is no resource on that same name (ubuntu915..)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand or if I misunderstood.. If I give unique name then it'll create a new interface. I want to modify the existing interface not create a new one.

Comment: Just trying to know if you trying to rename the network interface please try with some other name which is not exist. Because the error clearly states that you have `ubuntu915` under the location xxx and rg XXX.

Comment: No I'm trying to change security_group for the network interface `Ubuntu915`.  `security_group: "testing_temp_8"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There were 2 issues.

Ansible was trying to create resource in the default region instead of actual NIC region. I had to provide the location `eastus`.

Also the VirtualNetwork was in a different resource group so in the playbook I had to  specify the resource group for virtual network.

```
  - name: Applying NSG to target NIC
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      name: "{{ azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].name }}"
      location: "eastus"           # This was important
      resource_group: "cloud-shell-storage-centralindia"
      subnet_name: "default"
      virtual_network:
        name: "testing-vm_group-vnet"
        resource_group: "testing-vm_group"       # Also I had to provide the resource group
      ip_configurations: "{{ azure_network_interface_info_modified.result.networkinterfaces[0].ip_configurations  }}"
      security_group:
        name:  "test-network_sg-6"
        resource_group: "testing-vm_group"
      state: present
```